# How could the Vue app pass the additional parameters to the event listener when using vm.$once()?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-events

In the **Vue app** , it could add the event listener that is called one time by using [vm.$once](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-once).
For example, in the child component of Vue App, it could emit the event using `vm.$emit('myEvent', data)`.   [emit event](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-emit)

And then it could be processed by adding the event listener to this event using `vm.$once` in the Vue app.
At this time, I want to pass the additional data to event handler.

I've tried as following. But it throws an error.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $event is not defined

```
    //In the Vueapp
    this.$refs.child.$once(
      'myEvent', this.eventHandler($event, additional_data)
    );
```

But I think that it could pass the additional data when using `v-on`.

```
  <child-component ref="child" v-on:myEvent="eventHandler($event, additional_data)"></child-component>   
   //$event is the data emitted from the event , "myEvent".
```

When using `vm.$once` or `vm.$on`, couldn't it pass the additional parameter?

**Note:** the reason that I use `vm.$once` is that I want to execute the `eventHandler` only one time when emitting the custom event, `myEvent` and add it dynamically .

Comment: How about to send reference of the parent to child component and emit the data with that reference?

Comment: I think that is not good way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to capture the arguments passed into the event handler. You can do this by using an anonymous function for the handler that calls your method. For example

```js
this.$refs.child.$once('myEvent', $event => {
  this.eventHandler($event, additional_data)
})
```

---

You could also get fancy with [`Function.prototype.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) however you would have to reverse the arguments list as `bind` prepends arguments.

For example

```js
methods: {
  eventHandler(data, $event) { // reversed argument list
    // etc
  }
}
```

and

```js
this.$refs.child.$once('myEvent', this.eventHandler.bind(this, additional_data))
```